# Grouping at high level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Customer_Name      Itemcode Order_Number    Quantity ord    u_es    Avail. Fulfillment%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle blaionuel   1019885  F130238518001   1           CET     0            0.00
oracle blaionuel   1132006  F130238518001   1           CET     1            100.000
oracle blaionuel   1016964  F130238518001   1           CET     0            0.00
```

I want to achieve an t-sql query that will introduce another column [Fulfilment% Order Level], which takes the least Fulfillment% of the 3 rows . I am using Mssql 2008
i.e

```
Customer_Name      Itemcode Order_Number    Quantity ord    u_es    Avail. [Fulfilment% Order Level]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle blaionuel   1019885  F130238518001   1           CET     0            0.00
```

Comment: what about the itemcode and the u_es? how do you pick those values instead of the other ones?

Comment: I guess tp asks for the row with the lowest Avail. Fulfillment%. But that's a tie in this case, and I don't know if that means return 2 rows, or how to pick one single row...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_name, order_number order by [Fulfillment%] asc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: looks like OP need lowest fulfilment% and there is a tie

Comment: @NoDisplayName . . . When there is a tie, I assume one of the rows can be chosen arbitrarily.